# What image format is easy to turn into on or off pixels?

Tags: .net, image, image-processing, bitmap

I have a hobby project that includes me driving a LCD by my serial port.

I'd like to display an image with 128x128 pixels, but I'm not sure what image format to use.  I'm limited to either "off" or "on" as a state of each pixel. What image format do you recommend?

In case it matters, I'm planning on using one of the .NET frameworks with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a Bitmap.

The .GetPixel and .SetPixel methods both use System.Drawing.Color values, an so are quite easy to work with.